John 1:3 says that all things "were made" through Jesus and not "are made". Does this mean that Jesus is not creating any new physical things?
John 1:3 ESV

All things WERE made through him, and without him WAS not any thing made that WAS made.

Notice that all translations render this in the past tense, not in a tense of continuation through the present.
I am curious as to why translations render this as "were made" instead or "are made", and "was not" instead of "is not"?
If all things are made instead of were made through Jesus, that would not imply that things keep getting created by God through Jesus, instead of that all things were initially made and set into motion during the 6 days of the Creation Week in Genesis (from God through Jesus the master workman) which God sustains up to this present day.
For instance, Genesis 1:1 says "In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth." But NOT, "In the beginning God continues to create the heavens and the earth."
It seems to me that God created all things through Jesus, his agent, in the initial 6 days of creation, and then this perfectly complete creation is sustained by God up through to the present day. There is actually nothing new being created (no new species, landmarks, heavenly bodies), and all things were initially put in place from God through Jesus, the Word and master workman.
Newborn infants are not a new creation, but the continuation of the initial creation in the Genesis Week, namely the physical DNA from Adam and Eve which contains all of the information for a newborn human to be formed in a womb.
Genesis 2:1-3 ESV

Thus the heavens and the earth were finished, and all the host
of them. And on the seventh day God finished his work that he
had done, and he rested on the seventh day from all his work that he
had done. So God blessed the seventh day and made it holy, because on
it God rested from all his work that he had done in creation.

This tells us that God (through Jesus) concluded his works of physical creation on the 7th day. This implies that no new physical things are being created after the Genesis Week. God used Jesus initially to set all things in place, and now He sustains them.
Your thoughts?

None of the verbs is present tense - why would you think that they are?  It would be helpful to apply Greek grammar.

Dottard - That's what I'm saying! So because this phrase is indeed in the past tense, this means that things are not still being created in the physical, but the physical things were created in the past tense. This means that God used Jesus to initially create all physical things, but that not God sustains this creation through his spiritual power.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You've changed the Title question to something different. It's okay to improve a Title, but after it has received an answer it's  not appropriate to change its meaning. Doing so can make the existing answers look very wrong, even though they were correct when posted.  For instance, Dottard's answer doesn't match the current Title question and appears to be answering a completely different question (which it is).

@RayButterworth - Thankfully, it doesn't change the context of the responses thus far.

Here are the verbs in John 1:3 -

ἐγένετο - (twice) aorist indicative middle voice, hence, "came into being"
γέγονεν - perfect indicative active voice, hence, "has come into being"

None of these verbs is in the present tense and so CANNOT be translated using words like, "are", "is", etc.  This is confirmed in -

Col 1:16 - For by Him [Jesus] all things were created [ἐκτίσθη = aorist indicative], in heaven and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or authorities—all things were created through him and for him.

Now, that fact that Jesus created all things does not mean that He cannot continue to create and sustain as per:

2 Cor 5:17 - Therefore if anyone is in Christ, he is a new creation. The old has passed away. Behold, the new has come!
Col 1:17 - He is before all things, and in Him all things hold together.

FINISHED ??
The fact that Gen 2:1-3 says that God finished creating the world does NOT mean that God is finished all creation; all it means is that God completed that particular task of creating the world.  Indeed, god is still in the creation business because we have several places where God is said to still be creating and will yet create such as:

2 Cor 5:17 - Therefore if anyone is in Christ, he is a new creation. The old has passed away. Behold, the new has come!
Eph 4:24 - and to put on the new self, created to be like God in true righteousness and holiness.
Rev 21:1, 5 - Then I saw a new heaven and a new earth, for the first heaven and earth had passed away, and the sea was no more. ... And the One seated on the throne said, “Behold, I make all things new.”

Again, Jesus is both creator of all things and sustainer of all things.  Further, if Jesus created all things, He Himself cannot be a created being.

Dottard - I understand that God created all things in the Genesis Week through Jesus his Word, but what I don't understand is how all things are "sustained" through Jesus, if not God and his Spirit?

Dottard - Also, I disagree that Jesus is the creator of all things. Rather, Jesus is the agent of the Creator of all things, which is God the Father. The Creator God used his "Word" to create all things, which was Jesus. When it says, "Let there be Light", isn't that God the Father commanding Jesus the Son?

@JoshuaB - I salute you that you understand how God/Jesus can create. Personally, I do not understand God's creation anymore than I understand His sustaining power, His incarnation, His resurrection, the virgin birth, etc.  I do not understand the mystery of godliness.  I accept them by them by faith.  Does this mean that you pick and choose what to accept by faith?

@JoshuaB - That is an interesting interpolation of the text in Gen 1:3 which is absent.  I am fascinated in the way you insert phrases to make the scripture fit your theology.  I am happy to accept the bald, unaltered text - Jesus is the creator and sustainer as per the quoted declarations above.

Dottard - I realized that "di autou" absolutely means "through him", and so I acknowledge that God created all things through Jesus. Nevertheless, I still completely disagree that Jesus is God. You see, even Jesus credits God his Father for creation, not himself. As God's Son, Jesus was simply following God's orders in Genesis to craft all things on his behalf as Mediator, Judge, and Builder. I think that all things were initially created, that is set in place, during the Genesis Week. Now the New Creation comes through Christ also. I think that newborns are not creations, but continuations.

@JoshuaB - the fact that Jesus created all things does not exclude the Father and the Holy Spirit.  All three, comprising ONE God created all things as per Gen 1:2.  This is not the place for debate.  Ask another question if you wish to pursue this further.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

No one uses the tense from a single verse to demand a conclusion for the entire work.

All things were made through Him, and without Him nothing was made that was made.

To illustrate, suppose "Him" referred to the Father.

All things were made through the Father, and without the Father nothing was made that was made.

This would not justify a conclusion the Father was not creating anything new. Rather it would be taken as an introduction to a passage which is going to say more about the Father.

In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. He was in the beginning with God... And the Word became flesh and dwelt among us, and we beheld His glory, the glory as of the only begotten of the Father, full of grace and truth...No one has seen God at any time. The only begotten Son, who is in the bosom of the Father, He has declared Him.

John's Gospel begins by making historical statements. In the beginning was, what was, became, what became, is now: what was with God is now with the Father. Again, using "Father" as an example, unless stated otherwise, this passage would not be taken to mean the Father no longer is able to do what He did in the beginning.
The passage is about what did happen; what  was the result of becoming flesh. Historically what was in the beginning with God, is now in the bosom of the Father.
There is no reading of the New Testament which allows one to conclude the Christ event degraded the Christ. That is, He is no longer able to do what was in the beginning. Quite the opposite, in addition to what was, the Christ is now more.

Is John 1 about the Genesis creation?
John chapter 1 is a contrast between Jesus and John the Baptist. This contrast begins with verse 2 and 7 where both were introduced with "this one", referring to Jesus and John the Baptist who were indicated later.
If John 1 is about the Genesis creation, what part does John the Baptist have in the Genesis creation? Moreover, why does John 1:8  say that John was not the light when light already existed before John the Baptist? John had no part in the Genesis creation, but he was involved with the beginning of Jesus' ministry. Jesus ascribed creation to his Father and  God and not himself. Mark 13:19, Matthew 19:4 and Mark 10:6.
Does this mean that Jesus is not creating any new physical things?
All creation is from the God of Jesus. No prophets, apostles and disciples taught that Jesus is the Creator.  Jesus never claimed to be the God of the Old Testament as Matthew 22:29-32 and Acts 3:13 show. The Old and New Testament says nothing about a co-Creator who is also God. Deuteronomy 32:6, Isaiah 44:24.
Matthew 22:29;31-32 ASV
But Jesus answered and said unto them, Ye do err, not knowing the scriptures, nor the power of God.
v 31 But Jesus answered and said unto them, Ye do err, not knowing the scriptures, nor the power of God saying. v32 I am the God of Abraham, and the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob? God is not the God of the dead, but of the living.
Acts 3:13 ASV
The God of Abraham, and of Isaac, and of Jacob, the God of our fathers, hath glorified his Servant Jesus; whom ye delivered up, and denied before the face of Pilate, when he had determined to release him.
Deuteronomy 32:6 ASV
Do ye thus requite Jehovah, O foolish people and unwise? Is not he thy father that hath bought thee? He hath made thee, and established thee.
Isaiah 44:24 ASV
Thus saith Jehovah, thy Redeemer, and he that formed thee from the womb: I am Jehovah, that maketh all things; that stretcheth forth the heavens alone; that spreadeth abroad the earth ( who is with me? );
Examining the use Colossians 1:16 to support that Jesus is the Creator, I find that, if Jesus is the firstborn of  creation and firstborn of the dead, then Jesus is not God. God does not die nor is He resurrected. Colossians 1:16 should be understood in light of Matthew 19:28
Matthew 19:28 ASV
And Jesus said unto them, Verily I say unto you, that ye who have followed me, in the regeneration when the Son of man shall sit on the throne of his glory, ye also shall sit upon twelve thrones, judging the twelve tribes of Israel.
If Jesus is begotten, the firstborn of the dead, the image of God, then he is not God. Being the firstborn from the dead, As the head  of the body [the church] all things hold together mean the under Jesus' leadership, he keeps the body functioning properly. This also describes the superiority of Jesus in the authority structure created and given by God.
If Colossians 1:16 is about the Genesis creation, how can Jesus be the firstborn of the dead when nobody has died yet?
John 1:3 Literal Standard Version
all things happened through Him, and without Him not even one thing happened that has happened.
John 1:3 NLT
God created everything through him, and nothing was created except through him.
John 1:3 NIV
Through him all things were made; without him nothing was made that has been made.
Note the inconsistent translation of egeneto as "was made" in John 1:3 to imply was created. The same egeneto is translated as became in John 1:14 but was simply translated as "was" in John 1:6. The word "egeneto" does not mean create or make.
In John 1:6 translators did not translate egeneto as there "was made" a man or this "was made" in Bethany.. John 1:17.
If the word egeneto in John 1:3 does not mean create or make, then the translations that show that "all things were made by him" or "all things were created through him "  appear to postulate an idea that is not present in the verse.
The word "through"  conveys the idea of an intermediary or an agent. If the "Word" is the intermediary or agent, then the word is not the Creator. That is why Jesus  attributed creation to his God and not to himself.
Mark 10:6; 13:19.
Thus, Jesus himself and the rest of the bible does not teach that he is the Creator.

The question seeks to explore whether Jesus is creating any new physical things, or not, based on the Greek grammar of one verse of scripture. Thoughts on the OPs view are sought. Unfortunately, the latter only causes arguments to arise, and the former only limits possible answers to exploration of that one verse. This site is not for debating topics, but before this question is (likely) closed down, I will give a scoped answer.
First, the verse in question needs the identity of this Creator cleared up. It is "the Word of God" who made everything that was made (hence, he could not have been made himself.) Further, "All things were made by him", not "through him", A.V. This Word of God existed with God from "in the beginning" and the link to the beginning of the material universe needs no further comment. However, the question asks about on-going creating by Jesus. Yet the text in question never mentions Jesus. Jesus is not mentioned by the apostle John until verse 16. This means that it is the Word who made all things (A.V.) and that he was not made at all.
If this is not grasped, there will be no understanding of this answer, which simply states that:
On the basis of the text in question, the Word made everything that was made. It says nothing more, or nothing less, than that.
In the course of time, "the Word was made flesh" in the person of Jesus (vs.14), born of the virgin Mary. This means that it is misleading to speak of Jesus as creating (making) all things. To be accurate, and to clear up misunderstandings, the Bible speaks of the Word in that capacity, and so should we (the Word also being identified as the Son of God, vs. 18 - "the only-begotten Son" in the bosom of the Father). But it wasn't until the Word, the Son, had human nature added to him that Jesus came into existence.
Now, as for whether further creating goes on, the Bible does not specifically say that it does. Disagreeing with your premise, every human baby conceived demonstrates God's creatorship ongoing, with human parents merely being pro-creators. God is Creator, ultimately, and the giver of life to all that lives.He gives the spirit of life to all, and it returns to him at the human's death (Ecclesiastes 12:7). In that sense, the answer to the question is that every new living creature that comes into existence owes its life, its existence to God. But the Bible does not go into specific new creations, except in the spiritual sense, of sinners becoming new creatures in Christ at their 'new birth'. That is a work of the Holy Spirit.
If you see in the Greek grammar of that one verse scope for saying Jesus does not create new things, you are free to hold that opinion and I am not going to argue about that. Other answers here have delved into that. I would just point out that the Bible says all things are to be made new, with a re-creation of a new heavens and a new Earth, the old heavens and the old Earth being consumed with fire at Christ's return (2 Peter 3:7-13). Yet this entails bringing in more scriptures. So, sticking purely to the one verse in question, it does not, in itself, say "Jesus makes no more things after the initial creation." The Greek grammar does not support that, as has already been explained. But as that is contested by the OP, I leave my answer as it is.

However doesn't Genesis 2:2 say that by the 7th day, God had completely  finished His work?

@JoshuaB  Your Q is about John 1:3 and you bring in Gen. 2:1-3 to support the notion behind the Q, which is fine. However, my answer is based on the view that the Genesis verses do not affect the John one, as this is not a matter of tenses. John shows (to me and many others) that the Word created time when creating the material universe, because he is the Creator. We likely disagree on this but comments are not for getting into debates. You have put your view, I have put mine. Perhaps you could put this topic on to Stack Christianity, seeking a particular group's views?

@Anne You say, "the Bible does not go into specific new creations,except in the spiritual sense." Psalm 89:47 "You created [bara] all the children of men."  If men born after Creation week count as new physical creations then I'm getting unsure of meanings.

@C.Stroud I said, "every human baby conceived demonstrates God's creatorship ongoing, with human parents merely being pro-creators. God is Creator, ultimately, and the giver of life to all that lives." That fits in perfectly with Ps.89.47. Thanks for quoting it. Yet we still don't have details, though the sanctity of human life screams silently from foetuses being willfully aborted. If there was no accountability before God for that, perhaps he has not directly created them? But I don't want this to explode into an emotive issue.

@Anne Reply received with thanks.

To create universe and to keep it into existence is one and the same action, for, as Descartes brilliantly demonstrated in his third metaphysical meditation, absolutely the same energy is to be exerted for keeping/sustaining something as it is to be exerted for creating this something, and, in fact, "sustaining" is nothing else than constant re-creation, i.e. constant bringing from non-existence to existence, at any given instance.
Thus Father and the Son - and also Holy Ghost for that matter - created the universe and constantly re-create it at any given instance and thus Father acts and the Son acts with the Father (John 5:17) and Their divine activity is one and cannot be separate, for which very reason those who have seen the Son (that is to say, the divine actions of the Son) have immediately seen also the Father (John 14:8-9).
In this light of identification of the act of creation and sustaining of the universe, the very question is incorrect and amounts to asking:
"Since it is said 'were made' and not 'are made', and since the universe henceforth continues to be, i.e. continues to be ongoingly and ceaselessly created, can we say that at a certain non-existing instance of this ceaselessness Jesus found His way to sneak away from the act of creation/sustaining the universe, put this task on shoulders of only Father and the H.Ghost, and Himself went to a retreat in a heavenly Honolulu beach ️ to drink heavenly piña coladas  enjoying Himself?" And the answer will be a big NO, because the Father is perfectly impotent to create/sustain anything without His Logos/Son - and His H.Ghost for that matter - so, had the Son sneaked away to the heavenly Honolulu, all universe would have been finished with all beaches, piña coladas and their consumers.

To begin, look at another text written by John.
1 John 4:2 This is how you can recognize the Spirit of God: Every spirit that acknowledges that Jesus Christ has come in the flesh is from God,
Does 1 John 4:2 imply that Jesus Messiah was born of a virgin, and was God? No absolutely not.
1 John 5:6 This is the one who came by water and blood—Jesus Christ. He did not come by water only, but by water and blood. And it is the Spirit who testifies, because the Spirit is the truth.
John states that Jesus Christ came in the flesh, and came in water and blood. That means flesh is water and blood. Is the Father ever described as being flesh, water and blood? No absolutely not.
And furthermore, both 1 John 4:2  1 John 5:6 use the Greek (G2046) which does not have the same meaning as G1096 “came into being, came into existence”
No, John 1 does not say that the WORD made or created. The Greek word γίνομαι defines as “to come in being”
Genesis 1:1 from a Septuagint text uses a different Greek word which is ἐποίησεν defined as “to make” which is translated as “created” from the Masoretic text Hebrew 1254 בָּרָ֣א
What “to come into being” means is explained beginning at Genesis 1:3 to the end of chapter 1. In other words what the WORD did was that to what is described in Genesis 1:2. GOD THE HOLY TRINITY created everything and the WORD then formed it and made it less empty and so forth which is “to come into being.” Genesis 1:2 is a distinct existence than what begins to happen in verse 3. Not the same reality. The heaven and Earth cannot return back to that state of reality. Time did not exist until verse 3. Light creates time, the separation from darkness which is worded as night and day.
Jesus is not the WORD. The WORD became flesh. Jesus is not the same substance as the WORD. That is obvious from that the WORD became flesh. A substance cannot become another substance without not being the former substance. Example: a man returns to the dust. A pile of dust is not the same substance as the man. The difference in substance is the “breath of life” Genesis 2:7, so as to distinguish between dust and man Genesis 3:19.
I’m not so ignorant to understand the two words as synonymous but since John 1 does not use the exact same word as Genesis 1 for “create” it implies that the author of John was trying to explain something much more specific which is not that Jesus, the WORD as flesh, God the Son, the WORD (logos) created everything in every sense of past, present, future. Not in this context of the Creation, if different words are used then those words have distinct differences.
Strongs G4160 and G1096 are not synonyms. Produce for me a Septuagint text where G1096 is used and I’ll reconsider my understanding of it as it is. Until then I will not consider that the two words are synonymous. If John 1 was intended to be understood as Genesis 1 then the exact wording as the Septuagint would’ve been used and then elaborated on from G4160.
More precisely, John 1 actually describes the new heaven and new Earth of Revelation 21. It has nothing to do with Genesis 1. Sorry. Bummer. Life goes on.
https://www.blueletterbible.org/lxx/gen/1/1/
https://biblehub.com/interlinear/john/1.htm

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
